# CSS Variables and Transforms

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've searched on here and via Google but haven't found an answer to my question, which is: "how can I use CSS variables in a CSS transform?"

In the HTML header I declare three CSS variables and their fallback values

```
<!Doctype>
<html>
    <head>     
        <style>
              :root {
                     --AHItop      : -260px;
                     --AHIleft     :   90px;
                     --AHIRotation :  10deg;
                    }
```

The actual CSS is:

```
 .AHI
    {
        position        : absolute;
        top             : var(--AHItop);
        left            : var(--AHIleft);                   
        width           :  250px;
        height          :  540px;
        z-index         :    3;
    }
```

In the Body of the HTML I create a DIV element:

```
<body>
    <div style = "position: absolute; 
         left    : 0; 
         top     : 0;
         overflow: hidden;">
```

And include an image in the DIV (and then close the DIV and body):

```
        <img 
            src     = "gaugesAHI.png"               
            class   = "AHI"         
        />
    </div>
</body>
```

Within the Script tags I have a bit of code to use the CSS variables:

```
<script>
    var pitch = 10;
    const elementAHI = document.querySelector('.AHI');
    elementAHI.style.setProperty('--AHItop',    pitch * 5.7 - 10);
</script>
```

This does exactly what I need and expect. However - and this is the gist of the question - I can't seem to use the same approach to include a 'rotate' transform in the CSS, i.e., including

```
transform       : rotate(var(--AHIrotate));
```

in the CSS and

```
elementAHI.style.setProperty('--AHIrotate', pitch);
```

in the script. I've tried it in IE and in Chrome.

I'm not an expert in Javascript and generally prefer the challenge of working things out for myself but on this occasion need to wave the white flag and ask for help - any of which will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know whether your actual code is the same, but you declare `AHIrotation` at the top but then use `AHIrotate` later.

Comment: are you adding `deg` at the end ? ...actually you have rotate(10) and it's not correct, it should be rotate(10deg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, a good way to work out the issue here is to put the variables into the CSS and see if it makes sense.

Initially, your variables are like this

```
:root {
  --AHItop: -260px;
  --AHIleft: 90px;
  --AHIRotation: 10deg;
}
```

So your CSS equates to

```
.AHI {
  position: absolute;
  top: -260px;
  left: 90px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 540px;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

This makes sense and works fine, next let's see what your javascript is doing.

```
var pitch = 10;
const elementAHI = document.querySelector('.AHI');
elementAHI.style.setProperty('--AHItop', pitch * 5.7 - 10);
elementAHI.style.setProperty('--AHIrotate', pitch);
```

First 2 lines don't need any working out the last 2 need a little.

```
--AHItop = pitch * 5.7 - 10
--AHItop = 10 * 5.7 - 10
--AHItop = 57 - 10
--AHItop = 47
```

And the next line is even more simple

```
--AHIrotate = pitch
--AHIrotate = 10
```

When we put the new variables into the CSS we get this

```
.AHI {
  position: absolute;
  top: 47;
  left: 90px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 540px;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(10);
}
```

And there we can see the problem we've lost our units. `--AHItop` requires px and `--AHIrotat` requires deg. We can add this in the JS quite simply.

```
elementAHI.style.setProperty('--AHItop', (pitch * 5.7 - 10)+'px');
elementAHI.style.setProperty('--AHIrotate', pitch+'deg');
```

Plugging in these changes it looks as though the CSS will be able to work out what is going on.

I hope that all makes sense

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, could you [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)? Thanks 